# Raster correlation and p-values from cor.test

Tags: r, correlation, raster, pearson, p-value

I am trying to get pixel-wise correlations and significance (p-value) between two raster bricks using `cor` and `cor.test`. My data are here:

- [Brick 1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bzgz2w7ao8kld27/pet.zip)
- [Brick 2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jyuc0u0pt3bozn4/rain.zip)

They're both fairly small, less than 2MB altogether.

I found the following two codes (both from Robert Hijmans) from a previous discussions on StackOverflow and r-sig-geo:

```
#load data
require(raster)
sa <- brick("rain.grd")
sb <- brick("pet.grd")

# code 1
funcal <- function(xy) {
    xy <- na.omit(matrix(xy, ncol=2))
    if (ncol(xy) < 2) {
        NA
    } else {
        cor(xy[, 1], xy[, 2])
    }
}
s <- stack(sa, sb)
calc(s, funcal)
# code 2
stackcor <- function(s1, s2, method='spearman') { 
        mycor <- function(v) { 
                x <- v[1:split] 
                y <- v[(split+1):(2*split)] 
                cor(x, y, method=method) 
        } 
        s <- stack(s1, s2) 
        split <- nlayers(s)/2 
        calc(s, fun=mycor ) 
}
```

Both codes work as expected with the `cor` function producing correlation grids. However, I tried substituting the `cor` with `cor.test` in order to extract the p-values:

```
# using the first code
funcal <- function(xy) {
    xy <- na.omit(matrix(xy, ncol=2))
    if (ncol(xy) < 2) {
        NA
    } else {
        cor.test(xy[, 1], xy[, 2],method="pearson")$p.value
    }
}
s <- stack(sa, sb)
calc(s, funcal)
```

I am met with the following error (with trackback in RStudio):

```
Error in cor.test.default(xy[, 1], xy[, 2], method = "pearson") : 
  not enough finite observations 
8 stop("not enough finite observations") 
7 cor.test.default(xy[, 1], xy[, 2], method = "pearson") 
6 cor.test(xy[, 1], xy[, 2], method = "pearson") 
5 FUN(newX[, i], ...) 
4 apply(v, 1, fun) 
3 .local(x, fun, ...) 
2 calc(meistack, brick.cor.pval) 
1 calc(meistack, brick.cor.pval)
```

In a previous r-sig-geo discussion, a user had asked about this error but it was left unanswered. So I asked again and received one response to my inquiry where a user pointed out that `cor` is able to input matrices and `cor.test` cannot, but even after converting the data into a numeric vector:

```
cor.pval <- function(xy) { # Pearson product moment correlation
  xy <- na.omit(as.matrix(xy, ncol=2))
  x <- xy[,1:11]
  y <- xy[,12:22]
  #  if (ncol(xy) < 2) {
   # NA
  #} else {
    cor.test(x[1,], y[1,])$p.value
  #}
}
calc(s, cor.pval)
```

I am faced with the following error:

```
Error in .calcTest(x[1:5], fun, na.rm, forcefun, forceapply) : 
  cannot use this function
```

I was wondering if anyone can help with this?

My sessionInfo() is below:

```
R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] car_2.0-18          nnet_7.3-7          MASS_7.3-29         rgdal_0.8-11       
 [5] plyr_1.8            rasterVis_0.21      hexbin_1.26.2       latticeExtra_0.6-26
 [9] RColorBrewer_1.0-5  lattice_0.20-23     raster_2.1-49       maptools_0.8-27    
[13] sp_1.0-13          

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] foreign_0.8-55 tools_3.0.1    zoo_1.7-10
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference here is that they behave differently with empty vectors.

```
cor(numeric(0), numeric(0))
# -> NA
cor.test(numeric(0), numeric(0))
#->   Error in cor.test.default(numeric(0), numeric(0)) : 
#       not enough finite observations
```

It seems that your `na.omit` can remove all the records from certain combinations. Right now you only check the number of columns, when you should also check to see if there are any rows.

This

```
funcal <- function(xy) {    
    xy <- na.omit(matrix(xy, ncol=2))
    if (ncol(xy) < 2 | nrow(xy)<1) {
        NA
    } else {
        cor.test(xy[, 1], xy[, 2], method="pearson")$p.value
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks MrFlick, I tried the modified code above, and go the following error, it's the same as before: 

 `Error in cor.test.default(xy[, 1], xy[, 2], method = "pearson") : 
  not enough finite observations 
8 stop("not enough finite observations") 
7 cor.test.default(xy[, 1], xy[, 2], method = "pearson") 
6 cor.test(xy[, 1], xy[, 2], method = "pearson") 
5 FUN(newX[, i], ...) 
4 apply(v, 1, fun) 
3 .local(x, fun, ...) 
2 calc(s, funcal) 
1 calc(s, funcal)`

Comment: @H.Abdi Looks like `cor.test` may need at least three observations. Try changing it to `nrow(xy)<3`. You might need to keep increasing that till the error goes away. I don't know what the minimum number of finite observations is.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try different values and report back.

Comment: I've tried values 2 to 6. At values 2, I get the "not enough finite observations" response. From values 3 and up, I get a black raster as the output, as shown below:

`class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 273, 146, 39858  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 0.05, 0.05  (x, y)
extent      : 43.2, 50.5, -25.6, -11.95  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : in memory
names       : layer 
values      : NA, NA  (min, max)`

Not sure what else to try?

Comment: @H.Abdi Isn't that the same object that you get when you run the above code with `cor`?

Comment: Thanks @MrFlick, your suggestion was very useful in helping figure out the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use the function `corLocal` from the `raster` package.

> corLocal(stack1, stack2, test = T)

the returned results are rasterBrick with two layers, the first one 'r' value and the second one p.value
[image]